# Drive makes physical noises but system detects drive

Tags: hard-disk

*TLDR*: When I plug my drive in, I hear sounds that imply something has been detected/connected, but when I look for the newly connected drive I cannot see it. How can I find and possibly realign/fix the drive.

I believe this is not a situation that can be salvaged, however I have a drive with data that is not important so I took the front panel off to see what what was happening inside and if it was possible to fix and learn a little bit at the same time.

So, I believe the system reconises that a new device has been added (you can hear the system beep with volume turned up, in the video), but the drive is not reporting what it is? The drive is clearly struggling. I guess dead is dead.

Using `lsblk` I can see nothing changes when connecting the device:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyrAqhqA2Vw

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1944
loop1         7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop2         7:2    0  31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
loop3         7:3    0 341.3M  1 loop /snap/vlc/x1
loop4         7:4    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11107
sda           8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   128M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/users
sdb           8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2        8:18   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/tv
sdc           8:32   0  10.9T  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   0  10.9T  0 part /mnt/googledrive
sdd           8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdd1        8:49   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/oldgoogledrive
sde           8:64   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sde1        8:65   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/downloads
sdf           8:80   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdf1        8:81   0   450M  0 part 
├─sdf2        8:82   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdf3        8:83   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdf4        8:84   0 445.3G  0 part /media/hutber/E036A40336A3D934
├─sdf5        8:85   0   851M  0 part 
└─sdf6        8:86   0   450M  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 918.3G  0 part /
```

Comment: You might want to edit the above to actually include a clear *question*.  Also, if lsblk doesn't show the device, what makes you think the system is recognising it?  Being powered on and hearing mechanical noises is not the same as the operating system recognising a device.  Your title may be incorrect and need changing.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have updated the question with hopefully a more clear idea on what I am trying to achieve. The only reason is I hear the `Inserting a device` sound through the system sounds.#

Comment: Ok, so there's at least some recognition of its existence.  Looks like you might be using Ubuntu.  Does the Disks utility show anything?

Comment: Yep, exactly Ubuntu, Mint. Sadly nothing shows up in the Disks utility, however, the selected drive flashes. That is just to say, whichever drive I have selected briefly deselects then deselects whichever drive was selected before plugging in the drive.

Comment: Your video shows it struggling to read the inner track.  Have you tried changing the orientation of the dock so the platter is horizontal instead of vertical?  The current orientation means the arm has to 'climb a hill' to get to the inner track.

Comment: Makes sense ye. I hadn't tried this, but having just tried it. It was the same difference. IE it acted identically as the previous step seen in the video.

Comment: I think you're now limited to more 'drastic options' at this stage.  Gently heating it up with a blow dryer or oven.  Putting it into a zip-lock bag and putting it into a freezer.  Slamming it down onto a hard, flat surface.  That sort of thing.  Since the data has no value, I wouldn't bother with 'professional' recovery, or speculative component swaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120978/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-tim).